# how to set gradient color to stroke element in layer-list?

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient, xml-drawable

I have used layer list with two items. The first item display the gradient color and second item display the stroke element with corner radius. Here i want to add gradient color to stroke element.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#24615A"
                    android:startColor="#44968C" />
                <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="5dp"
                    android:color="#0AA4F1" />
                <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: does your code working or getting any issue ?

Comment: what is the issue that you facing?

Comment: i want to set start color & end color to stroke but  i have only one option to set color for stroke element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add another rectangle shape but adjust the item padding as follow:

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#f5e904"
            android:endColor="#ed0f12"
            android:startColor="#479644" />
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="7dp"
    android:left="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:top="7dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <gradient
            android:endColor="#24615A"
            android:startColor="#44968C" />
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>

</item>
```